# Using OrElse in a LINQ Statement

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following query:

```vb
Dim query = From m In Me.DataWorkspace.Products_dbData.MaterialList _
            Where m.ProductModel = Me.lblMyModel _
            And ((m.MaterialID = MyParam) OrElse (m.MaterialID.Contains(MyParam))) _
            Select m _
            Order By m.SortNumber
```

An excerpt of my data looks like this:

```
ProductModel        MaterialID           SortNumber
------------        -------------        ----------
111                 ABC_Material1        NULL
111                 Material1            0
111                 XYZ_Material1        0
111                 Material2_J          0
111                 Material2_K          1
111                 Material2_L          2
```

I have two scenarios that I would like to use the same query for.

**Scenario 1:**

`MyParam = "Material1"`

*Desired result:*

`query = "Material1"`

Meaning that `m.MaterialID = MyParam` matched and the `OrElse` short-circuited so `m.MaterialID.Contains(MyParam)` does not execute.

*Actual Result:*

`query = "ABC_Material1", "Material1", "XYZ_Material1"`

So for some reason I don't understand, the `Contains` is executing.

**Scenario 2:**

`MyParam = "Material2"`

*Desired result:*

`query = "Material2_J", "Material2_K", "Material2_L"`

Meaning that `m.MaterialID = MyParam` did not match and so `m.MaterialID.Contains(MyParam)` executes instead.

*Actual Result:*

`query = "Material2_J", "Material2_K", "Material2_L"`

So this seems to work as I would expect.

**Question:**

Why is this not working the way I expect it to? What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding the functioning of the `OrElse` operator but I can't seem to find an explanation that makes sense to me.

Alternatives and workarounds would be appreciated.

Comment: For your information: both `Or` as `OrElse` gets translated to the same thing in SQL: `OR`. But that's not what's wrong there as the answers mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meaning that m.MaterialID = MyParam matched and the OrElse short-circuited so m.MaterialID.Contains(MyParam) does not execute.

Well it wouldn't execute for *that individual value* - but it *would* execute for the other entries.

What you've got to remember is that your predicate is applied to *each* result. Whether or not there's already an exact match is completely invisible and irrelevant to later applications of your predicate.

As an aside, given that a string "contains itself" your predicate is equivalent to:

```
Where m.ProductModel = Me.lblMyModel And m.MaterialID.Contains(MyParam)
```

It sounds like you really want to do two queries: one exact match query, and then (if that doesn't find any results) a partial match query.

Answer (score 1):

You are understanding `OrElse` correctly, but not the way a LINQ query works.
The condition is executed for every row, independent of the result of the previous row.